# Table without using booktabs

Tags: tables, multirow, booktabs

I would like to know how to create the following table without using the package `booktabs`. Is this even possible?

```
\begin{table*}\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}rrrrcrrrcrrr@{}}\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 8$} & \phantom{abc}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 16$} &
\phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}\\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-8} \cmidrule{10-12}
& $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$ && $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$ && $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$\\ \midrule
$dir=1$\\
$c$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 && 0.3670 & 0.7187 & 3.1815 && -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\
$c$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384&& -9.0714& 297.0923& 46.2143&& 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
$c$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721&& 128.2265& -630.5455& -381.0930&& -121.0518& -137.1210&  -220.2500\\
$dir=0$\\
$c$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119&& 0.3593& -0.2755& 2.1764&& -1.2998& -3.8202& -1.2784\\
$c$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591&& -30.7381& -9.5952& -3.0000&& -11.1631& -5.7108& -15.6728\\
$c$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351&& 100.2497& 141.2778& -259.7326&& 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table*}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to use `booktabs`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the following is what you had in mind, but you could simply replace all rules spanning the complete width of your table with `\hline` and `\cmidrule` with `\cline`, like so:

**Code** (I'm using `\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}` because your table would otherwise go over the right margin.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}rrrrcrrrcrrr@{}}
\hline
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 8$} & \phantom{abc}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 16$} &
\phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}\\
\cline{2-4} \cline{6-8} \cline{10-12}
& $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$ && $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$ && $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$\\ 
\hline
$dir=1$\\
$c$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 && 0.3670 & 0.7187 & 3.1815 && -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\
$c$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384&& -9.0714& 297.0923& 46.2143&& 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\
$c$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721&& 128.2265& -630.5455& -381.0930&& -121.0518& -137.1210&  -220.2500\\
$dir=0$\\
$c$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119&& 0.3593& -0.2755& 2.1764&& -1.2998& -3.8202& -1.2784\\
$c$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591&& -30.7381& -9.5952& -3.0000&& -11.1631& -5.7108& -15.6728\\
$c$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351&& 100.2497& 141.2778& -259.7326&& 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Caption}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]